# Spring XD integration with hortonworks sandbox

Tags: hadoop, spring-xd

I am trying to do the Hortonworks tutorial "Using Spring XD to stream Tweets to Hadoop for Sentiment Analysis"

As part of the step I am using the command:

```
xd>xd-shell --hadoopDistro hadoop20

xd> hadoop config fs --namenode hdfs://10.0.0.27:8020

xd> hadoop fs ls /
```

At this point I get a timeout exception.

Thus, I used the next step of creating a stream

```
xd>stream create --name ticktockhdfs --definition "Time | HDFS"
```

At this point I get the following error:

> Caused by: java.net.ConnectException: Call to localhost/127.0.0.1:8020
>   failed on  connection exception: java.net.ConnectException: Connection
>   refused: no further  information
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.wrapException(Client.java:1142)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.Client.call(Client.java:1118)
>           at org.apache.hadoop.ipc.RPC$Invoker.invoke(RPC.java:229)
>           at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy52.getProtocolVersion(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)

I am using a Windows 7 laptop where I have the Hortonworks Sandbox.

In the Hortonworks sandbox setting I have:

1) Network --> Disabled the NAT driver
2) USing the Bridged Adapter --> Intel(R) Contrino(R) Ultimate-N 6300 AGN.

I am new to this, so pardon me if I have done small mistake

Answer (score 0):

I wonder if you have the correct IP address for the Hortonworks Sandbox - did you see that address as the Sandbox started up? See if you can connect to the Sandbox using `http://10.0.0.27:8888` in a browser.

What version of Spring XD and Hortonworks Sandbox are you using? It should work with Hortonworks Sandbox 1.3. The latest Sandbox 2.0 isn't supported yet in an XD milestone release (should be in the next release).

-Thomas